# Gamepad detected by lsusb but not by PCSX or jstest-gtk in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, usb, udev, joystick

I had been using a PS3 gamepad on [PCSX](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pcsxr/) for a while on Ubuntu 14.04, but realized it stopped working today.

The controller is detected by `lsusb` on Terminal, but it does not appear in **PCSX** or [jstest-gtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/jstest-gtk/).

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 10f1:1a43 Importek 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0930:0219 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 012: ID 054c:0268 Sony Corp. Batoh Device / PlayStation 3 Controller
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can confirm that this is a problem specific to trusty, since I tried to use the controller in a laptop with precise and it worked correctly.

EDIT 29 JUNE

Just found out that [udev seems to be broken](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2229082), and that this is a bug affecting several users. Apparently, the way of making it work is to [create your own udev rules](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2186521&p=13061148#post13061148), but that at the moment goes beyond my capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved in the latest update for **udev** in trusty, so just run the **Software Updater** or open a **Terminal** and enter

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```